# Error during downgrading from EE to CE in magento

Tags: magento

I am downgrading magento from EE to CE following the steps in http://blog.yanted.com/2014/02/21/downgrading-magento-enterprise-to-community/ and I am stuck at "Fixing Login". I have done everying in that step but I am not sure whether I fixed it. The situation now I am in is that I can open the frontend website, but cannot log in. At backend, I can login, but I cannot open "Catalog/Manage Products", "Catalog/Manage Categories", "Catalog/URL Rewrite Management", following error are returned (The main errors are the same: Invalid backend model specified: enterprise_targetrule/catalog_product_attribute_backend_rule, after "Trace", the content is different):

There has been an error processing your request

```
Invalid backend model specified: enterprise_targetrule/catalog_product_attribute_backend_rule

Trace:

/#0 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(346): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid backend...')

/#1 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(640): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getBackend()

/#2 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1624): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->walkAttributes('backend/afterLo...', Array)

/#3 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(964): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_afterLoad(Object(Loewenstark_ProductFinder_Model_Catalog_Product))

/#4 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(698): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Loewenstark_ProductFinder_Model_Catalog_Product), '6', NULL)

/#5 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Loewenstark_ProductFinder_Model_Catalog_Product), '6', NULL)

/#6 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/local/MageLine/CustomProductsList/Model/Observer.php(17): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('6')

/#7 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): MageLine_CustomProductsList_Model_Observer->addWebsitePricesToResult(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))

/#8 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(MageLine_CustomProductsList_Model_Observer), 'addWebsitePrice...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))

/#9 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)

/#10 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php(545): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)

/#11 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(885): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection->_afterLoad()

/#12 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(533): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()

/#13 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/local/Amasty/Pgrid/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Grid.php(163): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()

/#14 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/local/Amasty/Pgrid/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Grid.php(272): Amasty_Pgrid_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid->_prepareCustomSorting()

/#15 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Amasty_Pgrid_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid->_prepareCollection()

/#16 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()

/#17 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()

/#18 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

/#19 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)

/#20 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')

/#21 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product.phtml(46): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product->getGridHtml()

/#22 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/storage/www/ma...')

/#23 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')

/#24 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

/#25 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

/#26 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()

/#27 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()

/#28 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

/#29 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()

/#30 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

/#31 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)

/#32 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')

/#33 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/storage/www/ma...')

/#34 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')

/#35 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

/#36 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

/#37 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()

/#38 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

/#39 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()

/#40 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(180): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()

/#41 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->indexAction()

/#42 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')

/#43 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

/#44 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

/#45 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/app/Mage.php(685): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

/#46 /storage/www/magento_stage/www_stage2/index.php(104): Mage::run('worldwide', 'website')

/#47 {main}
```

Anyone knows how I can fix this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there are a set of product attributes that use an enterprise only backend model. My suggestion is to create a set-up script that goes and removes all of these attributes.

You can find these attributes by the following sql.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `eav_attribute`
WHERE
    attribute_model LIKE "%enterprise%"
    OR backend_model LIKE "%enterprise%"
    OR frontend_model LIKE "%enterprise%"
    OR source_model LIKE "%enterprise%"
```

Note that some of these attribute should be updated to use the normal non-enterprise model and some should be deleted all together.